# 複数のselect（disabled状態）を、順番に選択可能に

Tags: javascript, jquery

こんにちは。よろしくお願いいたします。
現在、jqueryを使って下記のような動きを試みています。

4つのselectタグ(0番～3番とします）があり、デフォルトでは

- select0(選択可能状態）
- select1～3(disabled状態）

となっています。

これを、0が選択されたら次の1を選択可能に、1が選択されたら次の2を・・・と順番に選んでいけるようにしたく、下記のようにIDを指定して個別に書く方法ではなんとかできるようになりました。

```
$("#select0").change(function(){ $("#select1").removeAttr("disabled"); });
$("#select1").change(function(){ $("#select2").removeAttr("disabled"); });
...
```

上記の書き方でselect3まで繰り返して書いています。

これを、eq: などを使ってもっとスマートに書きたいのですが変数？の書き方がわからず困っています。

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $("select").eq(ここに自身の番号に+1した番号).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

こんな感じでまとめることは可能でしょうか？
当方、javascript自体あまりよくわかっていない状態です。
どなたかご教示いただければと思います。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: unarist様

ご回答ありがとうございます。
ご教示いただいた内容で思い通りの動きができました！感謝です。

今後のことも考えて親要素で絞って使おうと思います。
本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.index(element)`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) である要素が集合の何番目かを調べることができます。

```js
$('select').change(function(){
    var curno = $('select').index(this);
    $('select').eq(curno + 1).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select><option>-</option><option>some</option></select>
<select disabled><option>-</option><option>some</option></select>
<select disabled><option>-</option><option>some</option></select>
<select disabled><option>-</option><option>some</option></select>
```

ただ `$('select')` としてしまうと関係ない `<select>` が増えたときに困るので、親要素で絞り込んだり、classを付けたほうがいいような気がします。

構造によっては [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) も使えるかもしれません。参考までに。